# how can I dynamically add DIV class="clear" after every third result when fetching DB when exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am kinda lost with what I am trying to achieve here, really need some help with the following.

While fetching DB using script provided below, I need to add `<div class="clear"></div>` after every third occurrence and if it is less than 3, lets say 2 or even one and there is no more after that after that last one.

Here is my script

```
<?
    $template_query = 'SELECT * FROM Files WHERE parentpageID = :id and show_in_category = "1" ORDER BY ID asc';
    $res = $db->prepare($template_query);
    $res->execute(array(':id' => $current));


$add_rowNum = 0;
while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
    $add_rowNum++;
    $templateTitle = $info['templateTitle'];
    $add_refering_url = $info['referring_url'];
    $templ_link = $category_folder.$add_refering_url;
    $teaserText = $info['teaserText'];
    $path_to_add_images = $image_path.$info['ImagePath'].DS;
    $add_img_info = $path_to_add_images.$info['templateImage'];
    $add_img_alt && $add_img_title && $templateTitle = $info['templateTitle'];
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($add_img_info);
    $last_class = ($add_rowNum == $res->rowCount()) ? 'frame' : 'frame frame_margin';

print<<<END
<div class="$last_class">
<div class="prod">
<div class="title"><a href="$templ_link">$templateTitle
<img src="$add_img_info" alt="$add_img_alt" $attr title="$add_img_title"></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="prd">
$teaserText
</div>
</div>

END;
}
?>
```

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008522/insert-tr-after-every-third-loop[link]

Comment: what about 5 records. It will having 2 div clear or just 1 after first three.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, it should have 2 div clear after 5 records, or if there is 7 records than it will have to be 3 div clear

Comment: You could make a variable to hold a count, increment that count each run. then use an if statement that checks if it is equal to 3, if it is print the div and reset count. then after the while check if the count != 0, if not print another div after the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
If(($add_rowNum % 3) == 0) {
   echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
}
```

Add this code after the **END** syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using with `%`

```
if ($add_rowNum % 3 == 1)
   echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this logic will solve this problem!

```
$total_records = 10;
for($i=1;$i<=$total_records;$i++) {
    echo "Hi";
    if($i%3 == 0) {
        echo "<br/>==================<br/>";
    }

    if(($i == $total_records) && ($total_records%3 != 0)) {
        echo "<br/>==================<br/>";
    }
}
```