# PHP Break Table Row on While mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have below code which is showing data in table td, Currently I am showing four table td but when I increase the no like 8 or 12 it is messing. I need to start a new row for every 4 td. How can I achieve this?

```
       <tr style="background-color:white;"> 
       <?php     
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {    
              // Display each field of the records.    
        ?>     
           
          <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;width:32px"><img styel="height:32px;width: 32px;" src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;margin-left:10px;text-align:left !important;">
                <!--<span><img src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/</span>-->
                
                <span style="">#Ad id:<?php echo $row["id"]; ?></span><br>
                <span style="margin-left:2px;border-top:1px solid blue;" class="node-text"><?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?> Has Added</span> <br>
                
                <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-15px;margin-left:2px;width:160px;" class="node-text"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row["url"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a></span> <br>
                
                <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-26px;font-size:smaller;color:silver;margin-left:2px;" class="node-text">On <?php echo $row["datetime"]; ?></span>
                
            </td>
        
        <?php     
            };    
        ?> </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert tr after every third loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008522/insert-tr-after-every-third-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... this is not the most beatutiful approach... But I guess it should work for you. I add a counter for `max_cols` and adds new `<tr>` every 4th cell:

```
   <tr style="background-color:white;"> 
   <?php     
    $max_cols = 4;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {    
          // Display each field of the records.    
    ?>     
       
      <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;width:32px"><img styel="height:32px;width: 32px;" src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;margin-left:10px;text-align:left !important;">
            <!--<span><img src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/</span>-->
            
            <span style="">#Ad id:<?php echo $row["id"]; ?></span><br>
            <span style="margin-left:2px;border-top:1px solid blue;" class="node-text"><?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?> Has Added</span> <br>
            
            <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-15px;margin-left:2px;width:160px;" class="node-text"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row["url"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a></span> <br>
            
            <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-26px;font-size:smaller;color:silver;margin-left:2px;" class="node-text">On <?php echo $row["datetime"]; ?></span>
            
        </td>
    
    <?php     
        $max_cols--;
        if ($max_cols == 0) {
            echo '</tr>   <tr style="background-color:white">'; 
            $max_cols = 4;
        }
        };    
    ?> </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to `echo` your `tr`/`td` and in every four rows `echo` new `tr`:

```
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {  
      echo $count % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>": '';
      echo "<td>Here is a content of your td</td>"
      echo $count % 4 == 0 ? "</tr>": '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to count each `<td></td>` in your `while()` loop.  When that count reaches your limit, i.e: 4, you start a new row and reset the counter to 1. You can set the number of `<td>`s per row with `$maxTDs` (below).

This is not tested, but should work and/or get you really close:

```
<tr style="background-color:white;"> 
<?php
$tdCnt = 0; // to start
$maxTDs = 4; // each row has 4 <td>s

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
    if( $tdCnt == $maxTDs ) {

        # close the row
        print "</tr>";

        # start a new row;
        ?>
        <tr style="background-color:white;">
        <?php

        # reset $tdCnt
        $tdCnt = 0;
    }

    // Display each field of the records.  
    ?>     

    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;width:32px"><img styel="height:32px;width: 32px;" src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/></td>
    <?php $tdCnt++; ?>

    <td style="vertical-align:top;margin-left:10px;text-align:left !important;">
        <!--<span><img src="<?php echo $row["gravator"]; ?>"/</span>-->

        <span style="">#Ad id:<?php echo $row["id"]; ?></span><br>
        <span style="margin-left:2px;border-top:1px solid blue;" class="node-text"><?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?> Has Added</span> <br>

        <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-15px;margin-left:2px;width:160px;" class="node-text"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row["url"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a></span> <br>

        <span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-26px;font-size:smaller;color:silver;margin-left:2px;" class="node-text">On <?php echo $row["datetime"]; ?></span>

    </td>
    <?php $tdCnt++; ?>

    <?php
};    
?>
```